# How to download Ubuntu offline installer server image

Tags: server

I want to download the ubuntu server image and install it without internet

I searched the internet for the server image and got `ubuntu-18.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso` which require internet to install

is there any image that does not require the internet to download?

I don't have the console so I cannot just click continue when it fails to connect to internet, as I am going to deploy this image as VM in KVM.

Comment: use the alternate installer (the one that used to be the only installer). Then at the step where it fails to to get an IP address via DHCP do this: "The installer will fail to acquire a DHCP address. Accept Continue, and then select Do not configure network at this time". [Reference](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/410/builds/207255/testcases/1441/results).

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: @rahulKushwaha The same basic bit applies - you need the Alternate Installer which will do what you're looking for - VM or not.  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.4/release/ is where you need to look (get the amd64 server iso from there)

Answer (score 0):

The images with the term `live` in their names almost rely on the internet.
To install the Ubuntu server without any internet dependency, it is better to download the desired release image from [ubuntu cd image sever](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/) and the one without `live` keyword in the name. e.g., `ubuntu-18.04.6-server-amd64.iso` for relative architecture (likely amd64).

These images can install without the internet. However, if they can access the internet, they will use it. To ensure offline installation, one needs to disconnect the machine from the internet or the whole network. In the latter case, one should choose the `Do not configure network at this time` option